# Save an instance of a program from RAM for quick starting

Tags: memory, adobe-photoshop, ramdisk, capture

Is there any possible way to save an instance of an individual program, after it has been loaded into RAM, then load that program back into RAM from that saved instance.

Here's a specific example.
I have a program (adobe Photoshop) which runs great on my computer. It renders fast, it has no lag, it exits quickly. The one thing it doesn't do is load quickly, it usually takes around... 8-10 min. I was wondering if there would be a way to capture an instance of Photoshop, running in ram (say, in a VHD or IMG file). Then load that instance back into RAM, instead of loading the programs' individual files and settings from disk.

I'm thinking of something similliar to a RAMdisk, but I have no idea if this even exists (if it doesn't, it should).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.

If a program is loading for 10 minutes, then it means it's doing *something* for 10 minutes. If it was possible to skip that *something*, it would skip it.

Computers are state machines and progressing from one state into another may take some time. In general [you can't just guess in which state the machine will end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Trust me, if it was possible in this specific case, Adobe would do it - they know that waiting for 10 minutes isn't fun.

The actual problem you have to solve is **find out what makes Photoshop start so long**. [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) may come in handy, but first I'd check if it's not due to third-party plugins, too many fonts installed etc.

Comment: I actually did a little test earlier with a program that always ends it's start cycle in the same binary state (Minecraft). I created a Windows XP-x64 virtual machine, with 4GB of RAM.  I used a 32-bit localized Java, and stored all runtime files in a RAM disk (The launcher, the java, the game files, ect). I then started MC, and waited for it to come to the intro screen. I isolated the instance of MC running in the VM ram by saving a snapshot, and editing the file. I then successfully re-deployed MC after a restart of the VM, so this proves that it's possible, if only in a vurtual environment.

Comment: Virtual machine is a separate computer, ie. a separate state machine. You can make a snapshot of entire state machine, but you can't snapshot a part of it and then restore it at any point (unless it's designed to work like this - VMs are, Photoshop isn't)

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I guess my only steps forward will be using hypervisors with dynamic virtual RAM to implement my idea; and I can not BELIEVE I misspelled virtual. If only comments could be edited this long after posting...

Answer (score 1):

If I may interpret your question, yes there is a way to accelerate your software and have things cached, if you are willing to allow for saved states, i.e. files under your control that merely need be opened upon user login and program settings that are always the same.

You can do this on a MacOS, Linux and Windows: Done correctly it can bring a great deal of system speed while reducing overall system temperature and extending useful media lifetime. There are several factors that will be important in deciding if this is good for your use case:

- Amount of physically available RAM (less than 8GB on MacOS or Windows 64bit is likely to be catastrophically segfaulty)
- Number of main programs and services that must be running
- Hardware performance and general specs

In specific cases where containers or VM’s are not possible or not feasible and either high performance and/or absolute reproducibility are desired, this is definitely the way to go.

On user login, a startup-script automatically reserves a piece of memory and creates a symbolic link in the form of a directory: a **ramdisk**. Then all program files and data files are copied from the SSD to the ramdisk. Then, the programs in question are autostarted, using settings that you have prepared and open files that have histories in systems setup to autostart.

The following is a kind of recipe that your script could follow.

---

Create a specific user profile that “contains” or has access to all of the programs and data that are needed; one where all non-necessary programs don’t run. Turn off services, programs, network connections, screen savers etc. and do it from the (user-based) system settings wherever possible.

Make sure you have a lot of memory and profile the system load in the circumstances you want to reproduce. Make a list of programs that you need: find the executables, temp file locations and user generated files and assets. Those are the files that you want to copy to your ramdisk. This is a good time to tune the size of your ramdisk. Rename the ***temp*** files and keep them as backups in the original location. Then create symbolic links that point from the original temp files’ locations to the ramdisk hosted ones. Copy your user assets as well and then call the program to initiate the user files you want it to open with - as well as any flags that you might need.

That’s all there is to it. Just don’t let your system hibernate or power fail...

### MACOS

> I do this for critical infrastructure on bare metal hardware
>   during art installations and audio-visual performances. I actually did
>   this recently on MacOS Sierra, in this case it was for a live video performance with resolume arena and screen capture with siphon.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use these cache dirs
dirs="com.resolume.arena info.v002.syphon.Syphon-Recorder"

# get available memory
size_mb=$(sysctl hw.memsize | awk '{print $2;}')

# use half the memory
size_mb=$[size_mb/2048]

origin="${HOME}/Library/Caches"
ramdisk="/Volumes/ramdisk"

diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "ramdisk" hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$[size_mb]

if [ -d ${ramdisk} ]; then
 for dir in ${dirs}
 do
  /bin/mkdir -p ${ramdisk}/${dir}
  if [ -d ${origin}/${dir} ]; then
   if [ ! -L ${origin}/${dir} ]; then
    /bin/mv ${origin}/${dir} ${origin}/${dir}.bak
   fi
  fi

  if [ -L ${origin}/${dir} ]; then
   /bin/rm ${origin}/${dir}
  fi

  if [ ! -L ${origin}/${dir} ]; then
   /bin/ln -v -s -f ${ramdisk}/${dir} ${origin}/${dir}
  fi
 done
fi

/bin/mkdir -p ${ramdisk}/Applications/Resolume
/bin/mkdir -p ${ramdisk}/RAMDISK_REPOSITORY/

echo "Copying Resolume to ramdisk"
/bin/cp -r "/Applications/Resolume Arena 5.0.2/" "${ramdisk}/Applications/Resolume/"
/bin/cp -r "/Users/Shared/RAMDISK_REPOSITORY/" "${ramdisk}/RAMDISK_REPOSITORY/"

cd /Applications/syphon
/usr/bin/open Syphon\ Recorder.app/
cd /Volumes/ramdisk/Applications/Resolume/
/usr/bin/open Arena.app/

exit
```

### LINUX

> In the Linux environment, Arch is a great platform where you can
>   really keep your installation lean by only installing exactly what you
>   need. In extreme situations, an engineer might choose to copy the
>   entire system folder to the ramdisk (e.g. from a relatively low-spec
>   read-only SD Card (to inhibit SD card corruption) or even from a network location. The code above should work with a few modifications.

### WINDOWS

> I haven’t personally done this on Windows, but it is possible. Check
>   this out if you need the ramdisk on Windows:

[Windows ERAM on github](https://github.com/Zero3K/ERAM/blob/master/install.txt)

Comment: I actually ended up using Virtualbox to achieve my goal. I loaded a lightweight copy of Windows 7 onto a virtual machine, and configured it to start in "seamless" mode and autohide the taskbar. I then created several copies of the VM and installed various high load-time programs on each of them, after which I created a snapshot of each VM with the program already loaded so it could be started nearly instantly. The best part is that I can start each VM with a desktop shortcut!